# Error for non english character in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

In the table of database collation of table is set utf_general_ci and character set is utf8. But when I am using the following query for selecting required data:

```
SELECT name_English,name_not_English    
FROM name_directory
WHERE name_not_English LIKE '%$name%' OR name_English LIKE '%$name%'
```

this shows error saying: "Illegal mix of collations (eucjpms_japanese_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'". Same results shows if I search with

```
name_not_english='%$name%' OR name_english='%$name%'
```

But if I search only with non-English character with the following query (using both like or =):

```
SELECT name_English,name_not_English
FROM book_store
WHERE name_not_English LIKE '%$name%'
```

then it shows correct result set. Using union which combined English and non-English query didn't solve this problem. What could be the problem?

Comment: Please include sample data, table and db definitions

Comment: Try changing `LIKE` TO `LIKE BINARY`

Comment: Thanks. It works with `LIKE BINARY`. What in case of = sign?